# PHP SOAP ERROR warning

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I get errors when accessing my application as you can see below dururuy everything is quite complex. Would you inform me as I needed. Thank you in advance.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in C:\wamp\www\gittigidiyor\class\client.php:1284 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://dev.git...', '', 1, 0) #1 C:\wamp\www\gittigidiyor\class\client.php(1284): SoapClient->__soapCall('isDeveloper', Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\gittigidiyor\class\client.php(97): ggClient->clientConnect('anonymous', 'Developer', 'isDeveloper', Array) #3 C:\wamp\www\gittigidiyor\test.php(8): ggClient->isDeveloper('tolgatasci', 'pass') #4 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\gittigidiyor\class\client.php on line 1284
```

Dear friends,
My local host soap client api 
Turkey GİTTİ GİDİYOR.com APİ sample REquest.

```
SOAP CLİENT
protected  function clientConnect($serviceAccessType,$serviceType,$method,$parameters,$xml = array()){
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
    $soapParams = array();
    if ($serviceType =='Product' || $serviceType =='Developer'){
        $url = 'https://dev.gittigidiyor.com:8443/';
    }else{
        $url = 'http://dev.gittigidiyor.com:8080/';
    }
    $url .= 'listingapi/ws/';
    switch ($serviceAccessType) {
        case 'anonymous': 
            $url .= $serviceType.'Service';
            break;
        case 'individual':
            $url .= 'Individual'.$serviceType.'Service';
            $soapParams = array('apiKey' => $this->apiKey,
                                'sign' => $this->sign,
                                'time' => (float)$this->time);
            break;      
        case 'internal':
            $url .= 'Internal'.$serviceType.'Service';break;

        case 'community':
            $url .= 'Community'.$serviceType.'Service';break;
    }
    $url .= '?wsdl';

    foreach ($parameters as $key => $param){
        $soapParams[$key]=$param;
    }
    if (count($xml) > 0){
        foreach ($xml as $xmlRow){
            $value = $parameters[$xmlRow];
            $soapParams[$xmlRow] = new SoapVar($value,XSD_ANYXML);      
        }
    }
    $soapParams['lang'] = $this->lang;
   var_dump($url);
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($url, array('login' => $this->auth_user, 'password' => $this->auth_pass, 'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC));
    $result = $soapClient->__soapCall($method,$soapParams);

    return $result;
}
```

SOAP URL https://dev.gittigidiyor.com:8443/listingapi/ws/DeveloperService?wsdl
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are not providing the required login credentials.
I'm guessing this is the php library that gittigidiyor provides. It has an config.ini file with it. You should assign values to the parameters in that config.ini file. Which will be used while creating a SoapClient on this line :

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($url, array('login' => $this->auth_user, 'password' => $this->auth_pass, 'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC));
```

Comment: can you access the getSales method? I am trying to use it on rest api but get an error. [GG-API-ERROR_511]. Were you able to use it?